# Cannot initialize the indexer process on Category Url Rewrite

Tags: magento-1.8, category, database

```
Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '66898000_1405186241-0-1' for key 'UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID'
```

I did a truncate on core_url_rewrite. When the following commands is executed:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

It executed successfully. Back in the admin interface, i tried to re index all. This error

occured again.

Comment: Have you cleared cache and you locks directory?

Comment: thank you so much. Clearing cache and directory locks solved the issue im having.

Comment: You are welcome, I put the above as the answer, please make it complete

Answer (score 1):

Clear cache and remove your locks folder from the var/locks